# How to set focus on a Vbox's specific child in flex 4

Tags: canvas, flex4, scroll, setfocus, vbox

I have a VBox which contains several Grids as its children. You have to scroll to see all the Grids. There are buttons in the Grids. If you press any of the button, it shows the children for that Grid's by removing all the Grids from the VBox and fill it with the children of that Grid's. There is a back button to remove the children and fill the VBox with the previous Grids. Now when I press back button I want to come back to the specific Grid from which I clicked to see it's child. If its at the bottom of the scroll then when I get back I will see that Grid instead of the top Grid.But it always shows me the top grid. I tried setFocus method. But it does not work.

I have a canvas as root parent and one Vbox as its child. And the Vbox contains all the Grids. And if you press the button of a Grid then Vbox will have that Grid's children which I explained above. The children of a Grid is also some Grids.

Please help with this. I am pretty stuck in here. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

`setFocus()` method only activates the component and not scroll the viewport. To do that you can use

```
var spDelta:Point = dataGroup.layout.getScrollPositionDeltaToElement(index);

if (spDelta)
{
    dataGroup.horizontalScrollPosition += spDelta.x;
    dataGroup.verticalScrollPosition += spDelta.y;
}
```

where the `dataGroup` can be your `VGroup`.

If this doesn't work or is not what you want, you can try to get the height of the component which you want to bring to view and move the scroller to that height

```
var index:Number = dataGroup.getElementIndex(comp);
var offset:Number = dataGroup.getElementAt(index).height;
scroller.viewport.verticalScrollPosition = index * offset;
```

Where `dataGroup` is your `VGroup` and `comp` is the Data Grid you want to scroll to.

Comment: Hi inquizitive. Thanks for your reply. I could not implement the first method you presented. It says VBox does not have any property called layout. The second method you mentioned I could not implement the scroller with vbox. I wrote it like this <s:Scroller id="scroller" > <mx:VBox id="vbox" width="100%" height="100%" >
  </mx:VBox>
 </s:Scroller>   But it shows error. The error message says "'mx.containers.VBox' is not assignable to the default property, 'viewport', of type 'spark.core.IViewport'." I cant replace VBox with VGroup for my purpose. Thanks for your reply :)